# Removing zero lines from dataframe yields dataframe of zero lines

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a script that has a bunch of quality control checksums and it got caught on a dataset that had no need to remove any samples (rows) due to quality control.  However, this script gave me an unexpected result of a dataframe with zero rows.  With example data, why does this work:

```
data(iris)
##get rid of those pesky factors
iris$Species <- NULL
med <- which(iris[, 1] < 4.9)
medtemp <- iris[-med, ]
dim(medtemp)
[1] 134   4
```

but this returns a dataframe of zero rows:

```
small <- which(iris[, 1] < 4.0)
smalltemp <- iris[-small, ]
dim(smalltemp)
[1] 0 4
```

As does this:

```
x <- 0
zerotemp <- iris[-x, ]
dim(zerotemp)
[1] 0 4
```

It seems that the `smalltemp` dataframe should be the same size as `iris` since there are no rows to remove at all.  Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copied verbatim from Patrick Burns's [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) p. 41 (I hope this constitutes "fair use" -- if someone objects I'll remove it)

**negative nothing is something**

```
> x2 <- 1:4
> x2[-which(x2 == 3)]
[1] 1 2 4
```

The command above returns all of the values in `x2` not equal to 3.

```
> x2[-which(x2 == 5)]
numeric(0)
```

The hope is that the above command returns all of `x2` since no elements are
equal to 5. Reality will dash that hope. Instead it returns a vector of length
zero.
There is a subtle difference between the two following statements:

```
x[]
x[numeric(0)]
```

Subtle difference in the input, but no subtlety in the difference in the output.
There are at least three possible solutions for the original problem.

```
out <- which(x2 == 5)
if(length(out)) x2[-out] else x2
```

Another solution is to use logical subscripts:

```
x2[!(x2 %in% 5)]
```

Or you can, in a sense, work backwards:

```
x2[ setdiff(seq along(x2), which(x2 == 5)) ]
```

Comment: Always good to see the R Inferno referenced and this answer means it might be a good time to review it again.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `which` to get your indices, I would use a boolean vector and negate it. That way you can do this:

```
small <- iris[, 1] < 4.0
smalltemp <- iris[!small, ]
dim(smalltemp)
[1] 150   4
```

EDIT: I don't think a negative index of 0 (as in your case) is allowed since there is no 0th index and thus R can't exclude that index from your selection. Negative indexing can be interpreted as: "give me back all rows except those with these indices".

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that in your second example, `small` evaluates to 0?

Taking the zeroth element of a vector will always return the empty vector:

```
> foo <- 1:3
> foo
[1] 1 2 3
> foo[0]
integer(0)
>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because of the rules of what to do with an index that is zero. Only strictly positive or strictly negative indices are allowed. As `[0]` returns nothing, and

```
R> -0 == 0
[1] TRUE
```

Hence you get nothing where you expected it to *drop* nothing.

The `identical(0)` issue is treated as indexing by a `NULL` and this is documented to work as if indexing by `0` and hence the same behaviour.

This is discussed in the [R Language Definition manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Indexing-by-vectors)